# How do I copy an element in java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to copy element from my array list then to pass it to my activity. Also in my if statement where I'm checking gfList is not equal 0 java complaining about Cannot cast from GroupedFeed to int. If anyone know what is the problem and can show me how to copy and past the element to my activity I would appreciate that. Thanks in advance! Here is my code:

```
 // I created my for loop but that did not work  
        GroupedFeed findFeed(String locateSport){ 
            if ((int) gfList != 0){
                for(int i = 0; i != gfList.size();i++){
                    if(gfList[i].category.equalsIngnoreCase(locateSport)){

                    }
                }
                return gfResult;
            }
        }

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                android.view.View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                long id) {
            switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition){
                        case 0:
                            // gfResult = findFeed("Men's Baseball");
                            Baseball();  // pass gfResult
                            break;
                    }
                return false;
            }

            private void Baseball() {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Baseball.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });   
        Main myMain = new Main();
        try {
            //  AssetManager aMan = getAssets();
            this.gfList = myMain.loadRSS();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Hosed");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my array-list:

```
this   Main  (id=831962574768) 
groupedFeeds    ArrayList  (id=831963150464)    
    array   Object[12]  (id=831963153088)   
        [0] GroupedFeed  (id=831963152968)  
            category    "Women's Golf" (id=831962986192)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963152992)    
        [1] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153592)  
            category    "Volleyball" (id=831962991720)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153616)    
        [2] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153744)  
            category    "Men's Soccer" (id=831962996544)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153768)    
        [3] GroupedFeed  (id=831963153896)  
            category    "Women's Soccer" (id=831963006320)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963153920)    
        [4] GroupedFeed  (id=831963154864)  
            category    "Men's Golf" (id=831963016488)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963154888)    
        [5] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155072)  
            category    "Men's Cross Country" (id=831963036816) 
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155096)    
        [6] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155224)  
            category    "Women's Cross Country" (id=831963041984)   
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155248)    
        [7] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155472)  
            category    "Men's Bowling" (id=831963093056)   
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155496)    
        [8] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155712)  
            category    "Women's Bowling" (id=831963098224) 
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155736)    
        [9] GroupedFeed  (id=831963155864)  
            category    "Women's Basketball" (id=831963170720)  
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963155888)    
        [10]    GroupedFeed  (id=831963157504)  
            category    "Men's Basketball" (id=831963299944)    
            feeds   ArrayList  (id=831963157528)    
        [11]    null    
    modCount    11  
    size    11  
loader  RSSLoader  (id=831962575480)    
aMan    AssetManager  (id=831962469744)
```

Comment: First fix your styling. I can't see what belongs to eachother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not include where you instantiate gfList though it is clearly not an integer. I assume you mean to call `gfList.size() != 0` or `!gfList.isEmpty()`

```
GroupedFeed findFeed(String locateSport){ 
    if ((!gfList.isEmpty()){
        for (int i = 0; i != gfList.size();i++){
            if (gfList.get(i).category.equalsIgnoreCase(locateSport)){
                return gfList.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then handle the possibility of getting null (not finding a match) when you call this method

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I tried but still complained about gfList where we have equals and in the next line where is return statement about: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<GroupedFeed>.

Comment: Oops. Had array type access [i] vs .get(i) which is for lists.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question for you, how to copy element from my array and then pass to activity? So if I take element [0] I have to copy that element and then pass it to Baseball if it's Baseball? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if (gfResult != null){ Baseball(gfResult); } What baseball does with gfResult is up to you.

Comment: In the line where you return gfList.get(i) I have to copy that element to gfResult and then to pass it to activity(sport). Can you show me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You try to cast a List to an int with this line:

```
if ((int) gfList != 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i != gfList.size();i++) {
    ...
}
```

`gfList` is a List and can not be cast to int. Maybe your values in the list are ints but the List itself is not an int.

Comment: If you want to check if a value is not 0 use gfList.get(indexnumber) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)

Comment: I think it's not clear what to OP try to do with this statement. Maybe he want to check that the List is not NULL. If this is the case then `if(gfList != null)` should be used.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me about how to copy element from array list and then to pass to activity?

Answer (score 0):

gfList is of a type that the compiler doesn't know how to cast to an `int`.  Assuming that check was to make sure there was something in gfList, you could try something like this (getting rid of the if because if there is nothing in the list, then the size will be 0 and I will not be < the size of the list):

```
            for(int i = 0; i < gfList.size();i++){
                if(gfList[i].category.equalsIgnoreCase(locateSport)){

                }
            }
            return gfResult;
```

There was also a typo in an if, you had `equalsIngnoreCase` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase` (extra n).

Comment: Thanks, can you help me figure it out how to copy element from the array list and then pass it to activity?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you meant to check `if(gfList.size() != 0)`. You don't really need that if statement, because your loop condition (it's customary to write `i < gfList.size()` rather than `i != gfList.size()` even though they are technically equivalent) would take care of that.

Or, if you wanted to check that gfList is not null, then it should be `gfList != null`. `0` and `null` are two very different things in java, unlike "C".

I am not sure I understand your question about copying objects. There is a `.clone()` method on a java Object. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I updated my question and at the very end it's my array-list. I want after I search trough array and pick element let say [0] take that element, copy and pass to the right place. So if we took Men's Baseball I want to pass that down there at Men's Baseball but I'm not sure where and how to pass that element. Thanks in advance I hope this help.